# Uninitialised NSNumbers, NSCFNumber and 0xb000000000000005

Tags: objective-c

I have Json response with values that aren't in quotes. Where the value is 0.0, it's getting created as a NSCFNumber with a value of 0xb000000000000005. This doesn't seem to be a nil or 0 value, so this is then causing problems.

Example JSON:

```
{ "MyValue": 0.0 }
```

My code:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSNumber *myValue;

...

[self setMyValue:[dictionary objectForKey:@"MyValue"]];
```

Leads to getting a correct value if MyValue was 4.5 for instance, but if it's 0.0, myValue ends up showing up in debug as = (_NSCFNumber *) 0xb000000000000005.

Where am I going wrong, and how can I detect this value which is apparently 0.0?

Comment: https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2012-07-27-lets-build-tagged-pointers.html

Comment: Thanks, I actually came across that one while searching and I'm still hugely confused. I don't quite understand if and how it applies to the practical problem I'm having. Perhaps I need to sit down and read it again.

Comment: I guess the 5 denotes it's a tagged pointer to an integer, but pointer to what? 0? I still don't understand how to identify it as zero.

Comment: It is not actually a pointer *to* anything, rather it is a value that _fits_ in the number of bits used to hold a pointer. It is "tagged" to distinguish it from an actual pointer to a memory location, so it can be passed around as if it were an actual object. Its numeric value is only retrieved when treating it as an object, such as with `po` in the debugger and with the `-doubleValue` method.

Comment: So I'm trying this: NSNumber *myValue = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithDouble:[dictionary objectForKey:@"MyValue"]]; but that gives Sending 'id _Nullable' to parameter of incompatible type 'double'. What can I do to actually get a NSNumber value of 0 where the JSON gives 0.0?

Comment: You already have one — your code is correct. That's why your debugger shows `_NSCFNumber`.

Comment: NSNumber is an object, not a scalar value.  If you want the scalar value, do something like `double foo = [_myValue doubleValue];`